# is there any option to escape value for i18next by different pattern and also plurals

Tags: javascript, react-native, i18next

1- is there any way to replace i18next [escape pattern](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape) ?

> from {{- name}} to be something like %{name}

2- is there any option to change plurals technique ?

> from

```
"key_zero"
"key_one"
"key_other"
```

> to

```
key: {
"zero": 
"one":
"other": 
}
```

expecting solving that from [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) for ex